# Cannot find title property of yAxis in HighCharts

Tags: angular, unit-testing, highcharts, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to verify in an angular unit test that a method in my component updates the title property of the yAxis accordingly. However, whenever I try to access that property, it says that it does not exist, despite being set in the method in the component

```js
private setYAxisTitle(yAxisTitle: string = ''): void {
    this.chart.update({
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: yAxisTitle
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional interface that extends the existing `Axis` with the missing `title` type.

**More information:**

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-yyy

**Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-property-xxx-doesnt-exist?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: How come I can assign the title but not read it?

Comment: You can also try to reference the graph by referencing it when updating. This is related to the way Angular builds the application, so it cannot be updated beforehand. Example demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-rznnzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts